# Как передать данные одного класса в другой С#?

Tags: c#

друзья! Возникла проблема. У меня есть два класса, два файла.(SMO.cs и Queue.cs)

Это код с файла Queue.cs:

```
public int counter = 0;

private void Elem_EventExit(Bid bid)
    {
      OnUpdate("Заявка номер " + bid.Number + " з типом " + (Type + 1).ToString() + " покинула чергу!", true);
        bids.Remove(bid);
      
        counter++;
 
    }
    public int Counter()
    {

        return counter;
    }
```

Я хочу вывести значение переменной counter в другом файле:

```
   Queue qee = new Queue();
   Console.WriteLine("Number=" + countNumber[m] + " Counter:" + qee.Counter());
```

Но постоянно выводит значение 0. У меня значение counter постоянно меняется , может проблема в этом . Нужно её решить и выводить постоянно новое значение переменной. Прошу Вас помочь, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Во втором фрагменте кода Вы создали Queue qee = new Queue(); и тут же выводите значение qee.Counter(), которое у Вас нигде  не менялось.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов , спасибо за ответ. А как тогда мне исправить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, но я сделал counter статичным и обращался непосредственно к нему:

```
public static int counter;

Console.WriteLine("Number=" + countNumber[m] + " Counter:" + 
Queue.counter);
```